# Android apply audio effect on all audio out

Tags: android, audio, driver, effects, post-processing

I am having one audio effect written in C, and i want to integrate my audio effect in android ICS BSP for custom board and effect needs to be applied globally if set once, regardless of audio playing application. Can anybody point me at which level i can integrate my effect? Driver level or post processing module of android (which module)?

I tried using 0 audio session id but it doesn't apply globally and also it is deprecated.

I need to have raw audio buffer in order to apply effect.
Please guide me to correct direction.

Comment: The first solution that comes to mind is to add your effect [to the set of available effects](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libeffects?h=jb_mr1), and force it to always be added to [AUDIO_SESSION_OUTPUT_STAGE](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp?h=jb_mr1) (must be done from within the mediaserver process).

Comment: Thanks Michael, Is there any document or guide anywhere? i dont have much hands on to the middle level of Android framework, I will have to study that part. Can this be simulate from application side?

Comment: None that I know of. Once you move below the APIs, the source code pretty much serves as the documentation. Perhaps there are people at the xda-developers forum who could provide more info. I'm not aware of any way for an app to forcibly add a system-wide output effect. Using session 0 is more of a suggestion to the system, which it can override (and as you've already noted, it's also deprecated).